# what is "Separate your URL links by a carriage return" in strapi?

Tags: strapi, media-library

Couldn't upload image using url in strapi. How to convert url into carriage return.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i0Ni1.png)

Comment: You don't have to convert URL into carriage return, if you have multiples images (do multiple URLs), separate them with a newline

Comment: I have tried to upload single image URL, but some URLs are not uploading properly.